# International mathematics olympiad solutions

Tags: contest-math

I want to prepare for math olympiad. IMO website provides the questions for past math olympiad.
Where can I find the solutions of past IMO problems?

Comment: Is it no longer the case that the national teams undergo some *training* and in that context (among others) walk through a lot of past problems?

Comment: I have searched and found solutions to many olympiad problems in the past.  Often the same site with the problems has the solutions.  What have you tried?

Comment: You can go through AoPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's just a few off the top of my head (I'm sure there are more):

The [AOPS IMO Collection](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3222_imo) contains virtually every IMO problem hosted on its online forum, and almost all of the questions have user-written solutions and problem discussions in the comments. 
In addition, AOPS contains many other contest collections from various national and international Olympiads.

On the [official IMO website](https://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx), you can download the problem shortlists for certain years. These contain all of the shortlisted problems (which include the 'official exam' problems) and their respective solutions.

[imomath.com](https://imomath.com/index.php?options=I&mod=23&ttn=IMO) contains a database of problems - Additionally, the website has published [The IMO Compendium](https://imomath.com/index.php?options=8&lmm=0), which contains problems and solutions to all shortlisted problems from 1959-2009.

In addition, John Scholes runs [a site](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/imo.html) containing all IMO problems and solutions from 1959 to 2003.

Note that the above are all 'databases' for IMO questions. In general for a specific question, if you just search your question, you'll probably come across a solution somewhere, whether it be on this site or somewhere else.

Comment: imomath.com has only the collection, not the solutions. Better go official site here : https://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx

it has practically all shortlists from 2006 to 2017, together with solutions. for previous years, simply use google

Comment: @Aaron Hm, my memory hasn't served me very well - thanks for the correction. I've still got the link to the official site above.

Comment: user574848, yes, realized you have exact same link. one more thing: Scholes' site (kalva) has not been active anymore. The versions that you've linked are accessed by some people.